# SQL : Select all Posts from Followers

Tags: php, sql, pdo, mysqli

Im trying to find an efficient way to display all posts from people who are being followed by the logged in account holder.

There are two key tables:

1- Posts

table name : `posts`

`id`, `account_name`, `published, body`

2- Follows

Table name : `follows`

`id`, `account_name`, `followed_name`

**I'm trying to find a way that i can display all the posts from all the accounts that are being followed.** The connection between Posts and Follows is the `Account_name`.

I understand that it will probably be a join, but it's how I construct the `WHERE` clause. So far I have the following (The account name is set via $_SESSION['account_name']):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN follows ON posts.account_name = follows.account_name WHERE  --- How would I only get the posts from the accounts being followed ?---"
```

I'm sure this is something simple my brain just feels drained and I cant seem to work it out.

**UPDATE Attempting in PDO**

Returning NULL at the moment,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM share_posts WHERE account_name IN (SELECT followed_name FROM $this->account_follows WHERE account_name = :account_name)";
    return $this->AC->Database->select($sql, array('account_name' => $account_name));
```

The goes to my Database Class:

```
    public function select($sql, $array = array(), $fetch_mode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
    {

        $stmt = $this->AC->PDO->prepare($sql);

        foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
        {
            $stmt->bindValue("$key", $value);
        }

        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt->fetchALL($fetch_mode);

    }
```

The returned data is NULL at the moment even though the logged in account has followed other accounts.

Comment: Can you clarify, is it a case of account_name follows followed_name, or is it followed_name follows account_name (who is following who from that table)

Comment: What's wrong with your query "as is" (without WHERE clause)?

Comment: @pburgess Account_name is the logged in account and the followed_name is the accounts that are being followed... Thus account_name follows followed_name

Comment: @LeeMarshall I believe my answer below then answers your question.

Comment: Hi @pburgess I updated my question, after just testing the it doesn't return Null, but how could i get the Account_names/account holder to get his posts within the followed posts? Thank for your time.

Comment: @LeeMarshall your inner query doesn't look correct to me, unless $this->account_follows is the table name. Try checking running the queries in phpmyadmin (or whatever you use). If you first check the inner query is returning results, then you know that this bit is ok, and you can focus on the query as a whole.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$account = $_SESSION['account_name'];

//do some sql injection checking on $account here

$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE account_name IN (SELECT followed_name FROM follows WHERE account_name='".$account."')";
```

This will get all the posts where the account name matches somebody you follow. I wasnt sure who was following who, but in this case the followed_name are the people account_name is following. If thats the other way around, switch the values

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE account_name IN (SELECT account_name FROM follows WHERE followed_name='".$account."')";
```

Comment: Sweet answer, thanks!

Comment: This is pretty outdated. You should use parameterized queries.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific please?

Comment: You mean to avoid SQL injection attacks?

Comment: Yes, dont sanitize input and append directly in the query, but use pdo to add parameters.

Comment: You got it, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

I will write this the way I interpret your question.

What you need to do is select only the posts from the users that are followed by your logged in user.

To break this down, first you want to select the users followed by the logged in user. To do this, we use the Follows table.

We then want to select the posts by these users. As such my query would be this.

```
SELECT posts.* FROM follows
    LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.account_name = follows.follows_name
    WHERE follows.account_name = $logged_in_user
```